# Colliders and Collision in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I am newbie in unity, i have one question. Now I am trying to collide my player with enemy. The problem is: after adding box Collider to my player his running is not smooth as expected, after removing box Collider his running and actions is good., i am using joystick controls for moving player.,

Thanks!

Comment: have you added a rigidbody along with the collider?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CharacterController instead of just using a static collider. The trick with the CharacterController is to use its Move() function to translate your object instead of using the transform directly. Otherwise collisions won't work properly.

Here is a link to the CharacterController :
[Unity Character Controller](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-CharacterController.html)

Here is a link to its Move() Method : 
[Unity CharacterController.Move()](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html)

Hope this helps!